# Complete Working Sample of the Gmail Three-Fragment Animation Scenario?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

TL;DR: I am looking for a **complete working sample** of what I'll refer to as "the Gmail three-fragment animation" scenario. Specifically, we want to start with two fragments, like this:

[image: two fragments]

Upon some UI event (e.g., tapping on something in Fragment B), we want:

- Fragment A to slide off the screen to the left
- Fragment B to slide to the left edge of the screen and shrink to take up the spot vacated by Fragment A
- Fragment C to slide in from the right side of the screen and to take up the spot vacated by Fragment B

And, on a BACK button press, we want that set of operations to be reversed.

Now, I have seen lots of partial implementations; I'll review four of them below. Beyond being incomplete, they all have their issues.

---

@Reto Meier contributed [this popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4819665/115145) to the same basic question, indicating that you would use `setCustomAnimations()` with a `FragmentTransaction`. For a two-fragment scenario (e.g., you only see Fragment A initially, and want to replace it with a new Fragment B using animated effects), I am in complete agreement. However:

- Since you can only specify one "in" and one "out" animation, I can't see how you would handle all the different animations required for the three-fragment scenario
- The `<objectAnimator>` in his sample code uses hard-wired positions in pixels, and that would seem to be impractical given varying screen sizes, yet `setCustomAnimations()` requires animation resources, precluding the possibility of defining these things in Java
- I am at a loss as to how the object animators for scale tie in with things like `android:layout_weight` in a `LinearLayout` for allocating space on a percentage basis
- I am at a loss as to how Fragment C is handled at the outset (`GONE`? `android:layout_weight` of `0`? pre-animated to a scale of 0? something else?)

---

@Roman Nurik points out that [you can animate any property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4936159/115145), including ones that you define yourself. That can help solve the issue of the hard-wired positions, at the cost of inventing your own custom layout manager subclass. That helps some, but I'm still baffled by the rest of Reto's solution.

---

The author of [this pastebin entry](http://pastebin.com/gh2eDkFS) shows some tantalizing pseudocode, basically saying that all three fragments would reside in the container initially, with Fragment C hidden at the outset via a `hide()` transaction operation. We then `show()` C and `hide()` A when the UI event occurs. However, I don't see how that handles the fact that B changes size. It also relies on the fact that you apparently can add multiple fragments to the same container, and I am not sure whether or not that is reliable behavior over the long term (not to mention it should break `findFragmentById()`, though I can live with that).

---

The author of [this blog post](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=758) indicates that Gmail is not using `setCustomAnimations()` at all, but instead directly uses object animators ("you just change left margin of the root view + change width of the right view"). However, this is still a two-fragment solution AFAICT, and the implementation shown once again hard-wires dimensions in pixels.

---

I will continue plugging away at this, so I may wind up answering this myself someday, but I am really hoping that somebody has worked out the three-fragment solution for this animation scenario and can post the code (or a link thereto). Animations in Android make me want to pull my hair out, and those of you who have seen me know that this is a largely fruitless endeavor.

Comment: Isn't it something like this posted by Romain Guy? http://www.curious-creature.org/2011/02/22/source-code-for-android-3-0-animation-demo/

Comment: @ferdy182: He is not using fragments AFAICT. Visually, it's the right basic effect, and I may be able to use this as another data point for trying to create a fragment-based answer. Thanks!

Comment: Just a thought: the standard Email app has a similar (although not completely identical) behaviour on my Nexus 7 — which should be open source.

Comment: The Email app uses a custom "ThreePaneLayout" which animates the position of the left-hand View, and the widths/visibilities of the other two Views — each of which contain the relevant Fragment.

Comment: @Christopher: That's very interesting. I haven't used the AOSP Email app, so I didn't realize that they used the same basic UI structure there as with Gmail. Note that I have no way of awarding a bounty to a comment, so you might consider writing up an answer with your thoughts on the `ThreePaneLayout` implementation. Thanks!

Comment: can you tell me Fragments A and B are measured? is it on linearLayout with weight attribute? Relative with standard DPs , Fragment A is  wrap_content and B fills the rest of the screen? Also Drawable caching is allowed ? ( meaning that layouts cannot update during animation)

Comment: @weakwire: "can you tell me Fragments A and B are measured?" -- either of your approaches would be fine, though I have a slight preference for the `LinearLayout`/weight approach. "Also Drawable caching is allowed ? ( meaning that layouts cannot update during animation)" -- :: shrug :: outside of perhaps using hardware layers in later versions of Android, I have not given that aspect much thought.

Comment: @CommonsWare "I have a slight preference for the LinearLayout/weight approach" so a custom (bootstrap style) ViewGroup that seperates the screen width with N equal units and each fragment takes x*N width space is allowed.(Almost what weight does but a bit more controllable)

Comment: @weakwire: Control is the key thing, particularly control that can be based on actual available space in the overall container (vs. calculating a bunch of dimension values, as the AOSP Email app does). However, "N equal units" is definitely not what I am looking for, as getting Fragment B to resize down to what Fragment A's size had been is a key tricky piece of this puzzle.

Comment: hey @CommonsWare I won't bother ppl with my whole answer here, but there was a similar question to yours in which I gave a very satisfactory answer. So, just suggestion you to check it out (also check comments): http://stackoverflow.com/a/14155204/906362

Answer (score 31, accepted):

OK, here is my own solution, derived from the Email AOSP app, per @Christopher's suggestion in the question's comments.

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Animation/ThreePane

@weakwire's solution is reminiscent of mine, though he uses classic `Animation` rather than animators, and he uses `RelativeLayout` rules to enforce positioning. From the bounty standpoint, he will probably get the bounty, unless somebody else with a slicker solution yet posts an answer.

---

In a nutshell, the `ThreePaneLayout` in that project is a `LinearLayout` subclass, designed to work in landscape with three children. Those childrens' widths can be set in the layout XML, via whatever desired means -- I show using weights, but you could have specific widths set by dimension resources or whatever. The third child -- Fragment C in the question -- should have a width of zero.

```
package com.commonsware.android.anim.threepane;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class ThreePaneLayout extends LinearLayout {
  private static final int ANIM_DURATION=500;
  private View left=null;
  private View middle=null;
  private View right=null;
  private int leftWidth=-1;
  private int middleWidthNormal=-1;

  public ThreePaneLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initSelf();
  }

  void initSelf() {
    setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);
  }

  @Override
  public void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();

    left=getChildAt(0);
    middle=getChildAt(1);
    right=getChildAt(2);
  }

  public View getLeftView() {
    return(left);
  }

  public View getMiddleView() {
    return(middle);
  }

  public View getRightView() {
    return(right);
  }

  public void hideLeft() {
    if (leftWidth == -1) {
      leftWidth=left.getWidth();
      middleWidthNormal=middle.getWidth();
      resetWidget(left, leftWidth);
      resetWidget(middle, middleWidthNormal);
      resetWidget(right, middleWidthNormal);
      requestLayout();
    }

    translateWidgets(-1 * leftWidth, left, middle, right);

    ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "middleWidth", middleWidthNormal,
                         leftWidth).setDuration(ANIM_DURATION).start();
  }

  public void showLeft() {
    translateWidgets(leftWidth, left, middle, right);

    ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "middleWidth", leftWidth,
                         middleWidthNormal).setDuration(ANIM_DURATION)
                  .start();
  }

  public void setMiddleWidth(int value) {
    middle.getLayoutParams().width=value;
    requestLayout();
  }

  private void translateWidgets(int deltaX, View... views) {
    for (final View v : views) {
      v.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);

      v.animate().translationXBy(deltaX).setDuration(ANIM_DURATION)
       .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
         @Override
         public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
           v.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
         }
       });
    }
  }

  private void resetWidget(View v, int width) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams p=
        (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();

    p.width=width;
    p.weight=0;
  }
}
```

However, at runtime, no matter how you originally set up the widths, width management is taken over by `ThreePaneLayout` the first time you use `hideLeft()` to switch from showing what the question referred to as Fragments A and B to Fragments B and C. In the terminology of `ThreePaneLayout` -- which has no specific ties to fragments -- the three pieces are `left`, `middle`, and `right`. At the time you call `hideLeft()`, we record the sizes of `left` and `middle` and zero out any weights that were used on any of the three, so we can completely control the sizes. At the point in time of `hideLeft()`, we set the size of `right` to be the original size of `middle`.

The animations are two-fold:

- Use a `ViewPropertyAnimator` to perform a translation of the three widgets to the left by the width of `left`, using a hardware layer
- Use an `ObjectAnimator` on a custom pseudo-property of `middleWidth` to change the `middle` width from whatever it started with to the original width of `left`

(it is possible that it is a better idea to use an `AnimatorSet` and `ObjectAnimators` for all of these, though this works for now)

(it is also possible that the `middleWidth` `ObjectAnimator` negates the value of the hardware layer, since that requires fairly continuous invalidation)

(it is *definitely* possible that I still have gaps in my animation comprehension, and that I like parenthetical statements)

The net effect is that `left` slides off the screen, `middle` slides to the original position and size of `left`, and `right` translates in right behind `middle`.

`showLeft()` simply reverses the process, with the same mix of animators, just with the directions reversed.

The activity uses a `ThreePaneLayout` to hold a pair of `ListFragment` widgets and a `Button`. Selecting something in the left fragment adds (or updates the contents of) the middle fragment. Selecting something in the middle fragment sets the caption of the `Button`, plus executes `hideLeft()` on the `ThreePaneLayout`. Pressing BACK, if we hid the left side, will execute `showLeft()`; otherwise, BACK exits the activity. Since this does not use `FragmentTransactions` for affecting the animations, we are stuck managing that "back stack" ourselves.

The project linked-to above uses native fragments and the native animator framework. I have another version of the same project that uses the Android Support fragments backport and [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) for the animation:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Animation/ThreePaneBC

The backport works fine on a 1st generation Kindle Fire, though the animation is a bit jerky given the lower hardware specs and lack of hardware acceleration support. Both implementations seem smooth on a Nexus 7 and other current-generation tablets.

I am certainly open for ideas of how to improve this solution, or other solutions that offer clear advantages over what I did here (or what @weakwire used).

Thanks again to everyone who has contributed!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the solution, but I think, adding v.setLayerType() sometimes makes things a little bit slower. Just remove these lines (and Listener too)
This is at least true for Android 3+ devices
I've just tried on Galaxy Nexus and without these lines it's working much better

Comment: "Both implementations seem smooth on a Nexus 7 and other current-generation tablets." I believe you; but I am testing your implementation with native ObjectAnimator on a Nexus 7 and it lags a bit. What would be the most probable causes ? I already have hardwareAccelerated:true in AndroidMAnifest. I really don't know what could be the problem. I've also tried DanielGrech's variant and it lags the same. I can see differences in the animation (his animation is based on weights), but I can't see why it would lag in both cases.

Comment: @Andrew: "it lags a bit" -- I am uncertain how you are using the verb "lag" here. To me, "lag" implies a concrete target for comparison. So, for example, an animation tied to a swiping motion might lag behind the finger movement. In this case, everything is triggered by taps, and so I am unclear what the animation might be lagging behind. Guessing that perhaps "lags a bit" simply means "feels sluggish", I have not seen that, but I do not claim to have strong aesthetic sense, and so what might be an acceptable animation to me might be unacceptable to you.

Comment: @Andrew: In terms of trying to figure if something is wrong, you might try the techniques outlined by Romain Guy in this blog post: http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/01/android-performance-case-study/

Comment: Yes, your intuition is on track. Lags = feels sluggish; lags a bit = feels sluggish, but not a whole lot, just a few dropped frames. Indeed, by using dumpsys gfxinfo I concluded the avg total compute time per frame is 18ms, which is above 16ms line. Anyway, maybe I'll open a separate question to not hijack your thread.

Comment: @Andrew: Just to confirm, are you encountering the dropped frames in my original project, or just in your project from [your follow-up SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665469/3-pane-layout-fragment-animation-is-stuttering)?

Comment: I haven't tested your project alone. It's just my implementation. So don't worry, it's most probably not your code at fault, if that's what you wanna hear.

Comment: @Andrew: It's more that there's a difference between my knowing that there's a problem in my code and my suspecting that there's a problem in my code. It'll just slightly change how I approach the problem when I look at it next week.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Chet Haase took a look at the code and posted a response on the question regarding the animation stutter. I already removed the ObjectAnimator and the requestLayout() call, but I still haven't figured out a way to simulate the Gmail animation, without doing a layout pass on every frame of the animation. If you do come up with an idea, do share it.

Comment: @Andrew: my best guess is that the middle pane is not being resized on the fly, but rather the left pane is sliding over top of it as part of the animation and the actual resize is happening at the end. That's just a guess. Implementing that would require a fairly complete rewrite of my `ThreePaneLayout`, as `LinearLayout` does not support overlaps on the Z axis.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I compiled your code with 4.2, great work. When I tapped on middle `ListView` and pressed back button quickly and repeated then whole Layout drifted to right. It started showing extra space column on left. This behavior introduced because I wouldn't let the first animation (started by tap on middle `ListView`) complete and pressed the back button. I fixed it by replacing `translationXBy` with `translationX` in `translateWidgets` method and `translateWidgets(leftWidth, left, middle, right);` with `translateWidgets(0, left, middle, right);` in `showLeft()` method.

Comment: I also replaced `requestLayout();` with `middle.requestLayout();` in `setMiddleWidth(int value);` method. It may not effect performance as I guess GPU will still do a full layout pass, any comments?

Comment: @M-WaJeEh: At some point, I will try to replicate your results, but it may be a few days before I can do that.

Comment: Mark, I came across the same problem as @M-WaJeEh by using the Android Monkey (fast random clicking) on it. The proposed solution (absolute translation instead of relative) seems to fix it completely for me. I propose you copy it.

Answer (score 67):

Uploaded my proposal at [github](https://github.com/weakwire/3PaneLayout) 
(Is working with all android versions though view hardware acceleration is strongly recommended for this kind of animations. For non hardware accelerated devices a bitmap caching implementation should fit better)

Demo video with the animation is [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lZuyY6DFXQ) (Slow frame rate cause of the screen cast. Actual performance is very fast)

---

**Usage:**

```
layout = new ThreeLayout(this, 3);
layout.setAnimationDuration(1000);
setContentView(layout);
layout.getLeftView();   //<---inflate FragmentA here
layout.getMiddleView(); //<---inflate FragmentB here
layout.getRightView();  //<---inflate FragmentC here

//Left Animation set
layout.startLeftAnimation();

//Right Animation set
layout.startRightAnimation();

//You can even set interpolators
```

---

**Explaination**:

Created a new custom **RelativeLayout(ThreeLayout)** and 2 custom Animations(MyScalAnimation, MyTranslateAnimation)

`ThreeLayout` gets the weight of the left pane as param ,assuming the other visible view has `weight=1`.

So `new ThreeLayout(context,3)` creates a new view with 3 children and the left pane with have 1/3 of the total screen. The other view occupies the all available space.

> It calculates width at runtime,a safer implementation is that the dimentions are be calculated first time in draw(). instead of in post()

Scale and Translate animations actually resize and move the view and not pseudo-[scale,move]. Notice that `fillAfter(true)` is not used anywhere.

View2 is right_of View1

and

View3 is right_of View2

Having set these rules RelativeLayout takes care of everything else. Animations alter the `margins` (on move) and `[width,height]` on scale

To access each child (so that you can inflate it with your Fragment you can call

```
public FrameLayout getLeftLayout() {}

public FrameLayout getMiddleLayout() {}

public FrameLayout getRightLayout() {}
```

Below are demonstrated the 2 animations

---

Stage1

> ---IN Screen----------!-----OUT----
>
> [View1][_____View2_____][_____View3_____]

Stage2

> --OUT-!--------IN Screen------
>
> [View1][View2][_____View3_____]

Comment: While I have not implemented a scale animator yet, I am concerned that it will work well for solid fields of color and less well on, shall we say, "real" content. The results of Fragment B being resized to fit Fragment A's space should be no different than if Fragment B had been put there originally. For example, AFAIK, a scale animator will scale the font size (by drawing everything in the animated `View` smaller), but in Gmail/Email, we don't get smaller fonts, just fewer words.

Comment: @CommonsWare scaleAnimation is just an abstract name. In fact no scaling takes place. It actually resizes the view's width. Check the source. LayoutResizer might be a better name for it.

Comment: That is not my interpretation of the source around the `scaleX` value on `View`, though I may be misinterpreting things.

Comment: @CommonsWare check this https://github.com/weakwire/3PaneLayout/blob/master/src/com/example/MyScaleAnimation.java out. The only reason i extend Animation is to get access to to the interpolatedTime .  p.width = (int) width; does all the magic and it's not scaleX. It's actual view dimentions that alter during the specified time.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my mistake. I was reading your comment and not cross-checking it with your source at that moment. Thanks! I came up with another solution, in parallel to your own development, though at the moment you are "the leader in the clubhouse" to get the bounty: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12318422/115145

Comment: You video shows a good framerate, but the views used in your example are very simple. Doing a requestLayout() during an animation is very costly. Especially if the children are complex (a ListView for example). This will probably result in a choppy animation. The GMail app does not call requestLayout. Instead, another smaller view is put into the middle panel just before the animation starts.

Comment: @weakwire is there by any chance a way to create a layout that will appear from the top?

Comment: @meh yes i don't see any limitation on that matter. Just set your layout with RelativeLayout params and later margins.

Answer (score 13):

We built a library called PanesLibrary which solves this problem. It's even more flexible than what's been previously offered because:

- Each pane can be dynamically sized
- It allows for any number of panes (not just 2 or 3)
- Fragments inside of panes are correctly retained on orientation changes.

You can check it out here: https://github.com/Mapsaurus/Android-PanesLibrary

Here's a demo: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UA-lAGVXoLU&feature=youtu.be

It basically allows you to easily add any number of dynamically sized panes and attach fragments to those panes. Hope you find it useful! :)

Answer (score 6):

Building off one of the examples you linked to (http://android.amberfog.com/?p=758), how about animating the `layout_weight` property? This way, you can animate the change in weight of the 3 fragments together, AND you get the bonus that they all slide nicely together:

Start with a simple layout. Since we're going to be animating `layout_weight`, we need a `LinearLayout` as the root view for the 3 panels.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/panel1"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/panel2"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/panel3"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then the demo class:

```
public class DemoActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    public static final int ANIM_DURATION = 500;
    private static final Interpolator interpolator = new DecelerateInterpolator();

    boolean isCollapsed = false;

    private Fragment frag1, frag2, frag3;
    private ViewGroup panel1, panel2, panel3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        panel1 = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.panel1);
        panel2 = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.panel2);
        panel3 = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.panel3);

        frag1 = new ColorFrag(Color.BLUE);
        frag2 = new InfoFrag();
        frag3 = new ColorFrag(Color.RED);

        final FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        final FragmentTransaction trans = fm.beginTransaction();

        trans.replace(R.id.panel1, frag1);
        trans.replace(R.id.panel2, frag2);
        trans.replace(R.id.panel3, frag3);

        trans.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        toggleCollapseState();
    }

    private void toggleCollapseState() {
        //Most of the magic here can be attributed to: http://android.amberfog.com/?p=758

        if (isCollapsed) {
            PropertyValuesHolder[] arrayOfPropertyValuesHolder = new PropertyValuesHolder[3];
            arrayOfPropertyValuesHolder[0] = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("Panel1Weight", 0.0f, 1.0f);
            arrayOfPropertyValuesHolder[1] = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("Panel2Weight", 1.0f, 2.0f);
            arrayOfPropertyValuesHolder[2] = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("Panel3Weight", 2.0f, 0.0f);
            ObjectAnimator localObjectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(this, arrayOfPropertyValuesHolder).setDuration(ANIM_DURATION);
            localObjectAnimator.setInterpolator(interpolator);
            localObjectAnimator.start();
        } else {
            PropertyValuesHolder[] arrayOfPropertyValuesHolder = new PropertyValuesHolder[3];
            arrayOfPropertyValuesHolder[0] = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("Panel1Weight", 1.0f, 0.0f);
            arrayOfPropertyValuesHolder[1] = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("Panel2Weight", 2.0f, 1.0f);
            arrayOfPropertyValuesHolder[2] = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("Panel3Weight", 0.0f, 2.0f);
            ObjectAnimator localObjectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(this, arrayOfPropertyValuesHolder).setDuration(ANIM_DURATION);
            localObjectAnimator.setInterpolator(interpolator);
            localObjectAnimator.start();
        }
        isCollapsed = !isCollapsed;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //TODO: Very basic stack handling. Would probably want to do something relating to fragments here..
        if(isCollapsed) {
            toggleCollapseState();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Our magic getters/setters below!
     */

    public float getPanel1Weight() {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)     panel1.getLayoutParams();
        return params.weight;
    }

    public void setPanel1Weight(float newWeight) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) panel1.getLayoutParams();
        params.weight = newWeight;
        panel1.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    public float getPanel2Weight() {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) panel2.getLayoutParams();
        return params.weight;
    }

    public void setPanel2Weight(float newWeight) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) panel2.getLayoutParams();
        params.weight = newWeight;
        panel2.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    public float getPanel3Weight() {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) panel3.getLayoutParams();
        return params.weight;
    }

    public void setPanel3Weight(float newWeight) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) panel3.getLayoutParams();
        params.weight = newWeight;
        panel3.setLayoutParams(params);
    }


    /**
     * Crappy fragment which displays a toggle button
     */
    public static class InfoFrag extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle     savedInstanceState) {
            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);

            Button b = new Button(getActivity());
            b.setOnClickListener((DemoActivity) getActivity());
            b.setText("Toggle Me!");

            layout.addView(b);

            return layout;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Crappy fragment which just fills the screen with a color
     */
    public static class ColorFrag extends Fragment {
        private int mColor;

        public ColorFrag() {
            mColor = Color.BLUE; //Default
        }

        public ColorFrag(int color) {
            mColor = color;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
            layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            layout.setBackgroundColor(mColor);
            return layout;
        }
    }
}
```

Also this example doesn't use FragmentTransactions to achieve the animations (rather, it animates the views the fragments are attached to), so you would need to do all the backstack/fragment transactions yourself, but compared to the effort of getting the animations working nicely, this doesnt seem like a bad trade-off :)

Horrible low-res video of it in action: http://youtu.be/Zm517j3bFCo

Comment: Well, Gmail definitely does a translation of what I describe as Fragment A. I would worry that reducing its weight to 0 might introduce visual artifacts (e.g., `TextView` with `wrap_content` stretching itself out vertically as the animation proceeds). However, it may be that animating the weight is how they resize what I referred to as Fragment B. Thanks!

Comment: No worries! Thats a good point though, this would likely cause visual artifacts depending what child views are in 'Fragment A'. Lets hope someone finds a more solid way to do it

Answer (score 5):

This isn't using fragments.... It's a custom layout with 3 children. When you click on a message, you offset the 3 childrens using `offsetLeftAndRight()` and a animator.

In `JellyBean` you can enable "Show layout bounds" in the "Developper Options" settings. When the slide animation is complete, you can still see that the left menu is still there, but underneath the middle panel.

It's similar to [Cyril Mottier's Fly-in app menu](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=658), but with 3 elements instead of 2.

Additionnally, the `ViewPager` of the third children is another indication of this behavior: `ViewPager` usually uses Fragments (I know they don't have to, but I have never seen an implementation other that `Fragment`), and since you can't uses `Fragments` inside another `Fragment` the 3 children are probably not fragments....

Comment: I never used "Show layout bounds" before -- that is very helpful for closed-source apps like this (thanks!). It appears that what I described as Fragment A is translating off-screen (you can see its right edge slide right-to-left), before popping back in underneath what I described as Fragment B. That feels like a `TranslateAnimation`, though I'm sure there are ways of using animators to accomplish the same ends. I'll have to run some experiments on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am currently trying to do something like that, except that Fragment B scale to take the available space and that the 3 pane can be open at the same time if there is enough room. Here is my solution so far, but i'm not sure if i'm going to stick with it. I hope someone will provide an answer showing The Right Way.

Instead of using a LinearLayout and animating the weight, I use a RelativeLayout and animate the margins. I'm not sure it's the best way because it require a call to requestLayout() at each update. It's smooth on all my devices though.

So, I animate the layout, i am not using fragments transaction. I handle the back button manually to close fragment C if it is open.

FragmentB use layout_toLeftOf/ToRightOf to keep it aligned to fragment A and C.

When my app trigger an event to display fragment C, I slide-in fragment C, and i slide-out fragment A at the same time. (2 separate animation). Inversely, when Fragment A open, i close C at the same time.

In portrait mode or on smaller screen, i use a slightly different layout and slide Fragment C over the screen.

To use percentage for the width of Fragment A and C, i think you would have to compute it at run time... (?)

Here is the activity's layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootpane"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- FRAGMENT A -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_A"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.xyz.fragA" />

    <!-- FRAGMENT C -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_C"
        android:layout_width="600dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        class="com.xyz.fragC"/>

    <!-- FRAGMENT B -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_B"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/fragment_C"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fragment_A"
        class="com.xyz.fragB" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The animation to slide FragmentC in or out:

```
private ValueAnimator createFragmentCAnimation(final View fragmentCRootView, boolean slideIn) {

    ValueAnimator anim = null;

    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) fragmentCRootView.getLayoutParams();
    if (slideIn) {
        // set the rightMargin so the view is just outside the right edge of the screen.
        lp.rightMargin = -(lp.width);
        // the view's visibility was GONE, make it VISIBLE
        fragmentCRootView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(lp.rightMargin, 0);
    } else
        // slide out: animate rightMargin until the view is outside the screen
        anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, -(lp.width));

    anim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(5));
    anim.setDuration(300);
    anim.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            Integer rightMargin = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            lp.rightMargin = rightMargin;
            fragmentCRootView.requestLayout();
        }
    });

    if (!slideIn) {
        // if the view was sliding out, set visibility to GONE once the animation is done
        anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                fragmentCRootView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
    return anim;
}
```