# How do I move and change fragment view size

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an activity with two fragments like this image :
[status A](http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/1083/astatus.png)
Fragment B is a ListFragment. When user clicks on one row in fragment B. I have show detail. And the UI should like this:
[status B](http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/1984/bstatus.png)

How can I move and resize fragment B?

I tried this way but don't know whether it is a correct way or hacky way.
I set this layout for the activity.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutMainPart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/scrollViewBottomMenu"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scrollViewLeftMenu"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/leftContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/rightContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I create 3 fragment A, B, C class. When the activity create I add two fragment A, B to leftContainer and rightContainer.
(fragment A layout width is fixed). When user click on one row in fragment B. I replace fragment A by another instance of fragment B (with different layout, and using the same data with the old fragment B instance). And replace fragment B in rightContainer by an instance of fragment C.

In fragment B class. I have flag to choose layout when onCreateView method is called, something like :

```
if(rightPosition) 
    return B_right_pos_layout;
else
    return B_left_pos_layout;
```

I think I can use the same instance of Fragment B. By doing like this :

```
    FragmentB fragmentB = (FragmentB) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_B_TAG);
    fragmentB.setRightPos(false);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(rightContainer, fragmentC);
    transaction.replace(leftContainer, fragmentB);
    transaction.commit();
```

I think this way is more like a hack way. What is the best way?

Comment: I think you're trying to achieve this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253965/complete-working-sample-of-the-gmail-three-fragment-animation-scenario