# Android - using the new design lib to create tabs with space below

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

**Update**
I was looking into this because when I changed the size of the spacer manually it caused stuttering and thought the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` will help fix it.
Reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/16103503/2482564 help me fix the stuttering by using ObjectAnimator and setting its duration to 0.

I'm keeping the question open in case someone has a solution with `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

**Original question**

I'm trying to achieve the following behavior with `CoordinatorLayout`, `AppBarLayout`, `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, `Toolbar` and `TabLayout` - whichever is appropriate for the task...

I want my initial view to look like this mockup
[image]

and the behavior when scrolling up should be:

1. the area marked in yellow disappears 1st
2. the area marked in blue disappears 2nd - it's only an area with color, no text
3. the area marked in pink - the tabs area, remains on the screen and is located at the top of the screen

I tried to work with the **cheesesquare** example and modified **include_list_viewpager** with the code below, but I get the normal collapsing tabs behavior with the shrinking title

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

any idea what should be changed to get the behavior I want? I tried other methods of changing the size of the spacer area manually, but it causes flickering on screen since I'm intruding in the middle of the scroll event

Answer (score 0):

Remove the app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" from your CollapsingToolbarLayout