# Android new Inbox app style listview with swipe left and right

Tags: android, listview, swipeview

m trying to build android new inbox style listview with swipe left and right as shown in this image , i have tried [47deg swipelistview](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview) but its not that stable , is there any other library available?!

[image: right swipe] 
[image: left swipe]

Tried so far with 47 deg

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        Listview pullToRefreshListView;
        SwipeListView swipelistview;
        ItemAdapter adapter;
        List<ItemRow> itemData;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            pullToRefreshListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.example_swipe_lv_list);
            swipelistview = pullToRefreshListView.getRefreshableView();
            itemData = new ArrayList<ItemRow>();
            adapter = new ItemAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_row, itemData);

            swipelistview.setSwipeListViewListener(new BaseSwipeListViewListener() {
                @Override
                public void onOpened(int position, boolean toRight) {
                    if (toRight) {
                        adapter.remove(position);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Open to dismiss",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } // swipelistview.dismiss(position);
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Open to edit",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onClosed(int position, boolean fromRight) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onListChanged() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onMove(int position, float x) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartOpen(int position, int action, boolean right) {
                    if (right) {
                        // adapter.onRight();
                        swipelistview.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.back)
                                .setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

                        swipelistview.getChildAt(position)
                                .findViewById(R.id.imageViewLeft)
                                .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        swipelistview.getChildAt(position)
                                .findViewById(R.id.imageViewRight)
                                .setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        // adapter.onLeft();
                        swipelistview.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.back)
                                .setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        swipelistview.getChildAt(position)
                                .findViewById(R.id.imageViewLeft)
                                .setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        swipelistview.getChildAt(position)
                                .findViewById(R.id.imageViewRight)
                                .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartClose(int position, boolean right) {
                    Log.d("swipe", String.format("onStartClose %d", position));
                }

                @Override
                public void onClickFrontView(int position) {
                    Log.d("swipe", String.format("onClickFrontView %d", position));

                    // swipelistview.openAnimate(position); //when you touch front
                    // view it will open

                }

                @Override
                public void onClickBackView(int position) {
                    Log.d("swipe", String.format("onClickBackView %d", position));

                    // swipelistview.closeAnimate(position);//when you touch back
                    // view it will close
                }

                @Override
                public void onDismiss(int[] reverseSortedPositions) {

                }

            });

            // These are the swipe listview settings. you can change these
            // setting as your requirement
            swipelistview.setSwipeMode(SwipeListView.SWIPE_MODE_BOTH); // there are
                                                                        // five
                                                                        // swiping
                                                                        // modes
            swipelistview.setSwipeActionRight(SwipeListView.SWIPE_ACTION_REVEAL); // there
                                                                                    // are
                                                                                    // four
                                                                                    // swipe
                                                                                    // actions
            swipelistview.setSwipeActionLeft(SwipeListView.SWIPE_ACTION_REVEAL);
            swipelistview.setOffsetRight(convertDpToPixel(0f)); // left side
                                                                // offset
            swipelistview.setOffsetLeft(convertDpToPixel(0f)); // right side
                                                                // offset
            swipelistview.setAnimationTime(60); // Animation time
            swipelistview.setSwipeOpenOnLongPress(false); // enable or disable
                                                            // SwipeOpenOnLongPress
            swipelistview.setSwipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList(true);
            swipelistview.setAdapter(adapter);

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                itemData.add(new ItemRow("Swipe Item" + i, getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
 public int convertDpToPixel(float dp) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float px = dp * (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
    return (int) px;
}
    }
```

Adapter class

```
public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemRow> {

    List<ItemRow> data;
    Context context;
    int layoutResID;

    public ItemAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<ItemRow> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);

        this.data = data;
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResID = layoutResourceId;

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    NewsHolder holder = null;
    View row = null;

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        row = convertView;
        holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, parent, false);

            holder = new NewsHolder();

            holder.itemName = (TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.example_itemname);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.example_image);
            holder.imageViewRight = (ImageView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageViewRight);
            holder.imageViewLeft = (ImageView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageViewLeft);

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (NewsHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        ItemRow itemdata = data.get(position);
        holder.itemName.setText(itemdata.getItemName());
        holder.icon.setImageDrawable(itemdata.getIcon());

        return row;

    }
    public void remove(int pos){
        data.remove(pos);

    }

    public void onLeft() {

        holder.imageViewLeft.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.imageViewRight.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public void onRight() {
        holder.imageViewRight.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.imageViewLeft.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    static class NewsHolder {

        TextView itemName;
        ImageView icon;
        ImageView imageViewLeft, imageViewRight;

        RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
    }
```

Comment: only this listview is available for this particular typr i.e someone swipes and buttons appear at the back. and i dont know y it isnt stable for u! i mean i am using it and it is working fine

Comment: @HirakChhatbar can you please read the issues on that stack , dont close the question if dont have answer or if u really found it stable you need to your code as there sample its self not stable

Comment: first, i havent closed the question. second, if it is stable for me (i am getting what i want), then y shld i revisit my code :p

Comment: why this question is been down vote ??

Comment: fyi: one of the reasons, probably evident, for close votes  
 *`Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it`*

Comment: in other words, what @user2450263 is telling you, could you please explain why the 47deg SwipeListview is not stable for you?

Comment: @MicheleLaFerla updated wot i tried and not stable

Comment: @user2450263 updated wot i tried

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857775/android-listview-row-delete-animation Check the example given by raghunandan,hope this will help you.

Comment: what about his library http://baoyongzhang.github.io/SwipeMenuListView/ ?

Comment: @rom4ek it doesnt have a directional swipe :(

Comment: @DjHacktorReborn - Were you able to find a working solution?

Answer (score 12):

Instead of using a custom ListView you can simply support "swipe" gesture on list items onTouch, like the following:

```
private static final int DEFAULT_THRESHOLD = 128;

row.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    int initialX = 0;
    final float slop = ViewConfiguration.get(context).getScaledTouchSlop();

    public boolean onTouch(final View view, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            initialX = (int) event.getX();
            view.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            int currentX = (int) event.getX();
            int offset = currentX - initialX;
            if (Math.abs(offset) > slop) {
                view.setPadding(offset, 0, 0, 0);

                if (offset > DEFAULT_THRESHOLD) {
                    // TODO :: Do Right to Left action! And do nothing on action_up.
                } else if (offset < -DEFAULT_THRESHOLD) {
                    // TODO :: Do Left to Right action! And do nothing on action_up.
                }
            }
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
            // Animate back if no action was performed.
            ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(view.getPaddingLeft(), 0);
            animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                    view.setPadding((Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue(), 0, 0, 0);
                }
            });
            animator.setDuration(150);
            animator.start();
        }
};
```

I also use reverse animation if no action was performed.

This solution is lightweight so you should not experience any lags.

Comment: `view.setPadding(offset, 0, -offset, 0);`  **-offset** for right side padding

Comment: can we hold it? until we swipe again?

Answer (score 12):

### Check out: [SwipeActionAdapter](https://github.com/wdullaer/SwipeActionAdapter)

It's a great library that does exactly what you're asking for. **It allows Swipe in both directions** with an underlying `Layout` or `Color`. It's easy to implement and looks nice!

[image: Left Swipe]
[image: Right Swipe]

Comment: can you share this project's source code please. I have looked up example that is mentioned in libaray but that isn't helping much.

Answer (score 2):

#### Updated Answer

As I mentioned previously, I took the same approach and it seems to work as expected. I have added 3 layers to a RelativeLayout. Top layer is what you want to show. Second layer is a plain background with delete icon at the left. Third layer is another plain background with share icon at the right. I implemented a swipe detector class which extends `View.OnTouchListener`.

```
public class SwipeDetector implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 300;
    private static final int MIN_LOCK_DISTANCE = 30; // disallow motion intercept
    private boolean motionInterceptDisallowed = false;
    private float downX, upX;
    private ObjectHolder holder;
    private int position;

    public SwipeDetector(ObjectHolder h, int pos) {
        holder = h;
        position = pos;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            downX = event.getX();
            return true; // allow other events like Click to be processed
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            upX = event.getX();
            float deltaX = downX - upX;

            if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_LOCK_DISTANCE && listView != null && !motionInterceptDisallowed) {
                listView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                motionInterceptDisallowed = true;
            }

            if (deltaX > 0) {
                holder.deleteView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                // if first swiped left and then swiped right
                holder.deleteView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            swipe(-(int) deltaX);
            return true;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            upX = event.getX();
            float deltaX = upX - downX;
            if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                // left or right
                swipeRemove();
            } else {
                swipe(0);
            }

            if (listView != null) {
                listView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                motionInterceptDisallowed = false;
            }

            holder.deleteView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            holder.deleteView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return false;
        }

    return true;
    }

    private void swipe(int distance) {
        View animationView = holder.mainView;
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) animationView.getLayoutParams();
        params.rightMargin = -distance;
        params.leftMargin = distance;
        animationView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    private void swipeRemove() {
        remove(getItem(position));
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

```
public static class ObjectHolder {
    public LinearLayout mainView;
    public RelativeLayout deleteView;
    public RelativeLayout shareView;

    /* other views here */
}
```

I have also added `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent` so that ListView (which is parent) doesn't intercept the touch event when there's some amount of vertical scrolling involved.

I have written a blogpost about it which you can find it [here](http://jayrambhia.com/blog/swipe-listview/). I have also added a [Youtube video for demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YH4b6ZIgjrI&feature=youtu.be).

---

#### Old Answer

I implemented one of these myself, but it's a bit different. I use just touch instead of swiping. Touch to open, touch to close. Here's [youtube demo](http://youtu.be/S--7XyE5hNk).

I created custom ArrayAdapter. To set the layout, I created a custom layout like this.

```
<RelativeLayout>
     <RelativeLayout>
          <Stuff that you want at the back of your list/>
     </RelativeLayout>
     <RelativeLayout>
          <Stuff that you want at the front of your list/>
     </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Using `RelativeLayout`, I am putting the top view over the bottom view. Both have same sizes. You can use different layouts for inner layouts.

In Custom ArrayAdapter,

```
@Override
public view getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // get holder and entry
    // set each element based on entry preferences



    holder.topView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              if (entry.isSwiped()) {
                  swipeWithAnimationValue(holder.topView, 1);
                  entry.setSwiped(false);
              } else {
                  closeOtherSwipes(entry);  // if you want to keep only one entry open at a time
                  swipeWithAnimationValue(holder.topView, 0);
                  entry.setSwiped(true);
              }
         }
   });
}
```

Normal Animation would not work as it just shifts the view, but it's still there so if you try to click, the click still occurs on the top view. Hence I have used valueAnimator and actually shifted those lists.

```
public void swipeWithAnimationValue(final View view, final int direction) {
    final int width = view.getWidth();
    Log.i(TAG, "view width = " + String.valueOf(width));
    ValueAnimator animationSwipe;
    int duration = 300;
    if (direction == 0) {
         animationSwipe = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, view.getWidth() - 200);
    } else {
         animationSwipe = ValueAnimator.ofInt(view.getWidth() - 200, 0);
    }

    animationSwipe.setDuration(duration);
    AnimatorUpdateListener maringUpdater = new AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {

             RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
             params.rightMargin = -(Integer)animation.getAnimatedValue();
             params.leftMargin = (Integer)animation.getAnimatedValue();
             view.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    };

    animationSwipe.addUpdateListener(maringUpdater);
    animationSwipe.setRepeatCount(0);
    animationSwipe.start();
}
```

Comment: dude there is no swipe happening i need swipe not not click

Comment: One thing you could do is, use onTouchListener. Get the coordinates of TOUCH_DOWN. mark it as your origin. And now, based on where the user moves the finger, change margin of the layouts to make it shift.

Comment: thx for telling me how to do it :) but i dont want to take this approach coz keeping such coordinate this is more poor than current 47 deg lib i need a better solution not a work around

Comment: Be cautious with this answer. It has the right idea, but setting LayoutParams is very intensive causing CPU spikes and lag ([see answer from lead Google UI engineer Chet Haase](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14780019/1226434)). Instead, use a setX property of the View. This also allows for a lot prettier animations using ViewPropertyAnimator.

Comment: Yeah, that is correct. But I didn't know about it back then