# Android listview row detail page sliding

Tags: android, android-listview, swipe, swipe-gesture

I have `ListView` which has many items(rows), `onClick` of any item goes to the `DetailActivity` which explains more about that particular item. If I want to see the detail of the next item, I have to come back to the `ListView` and click next item. How to design to see the next or previous item's detail from `DetailActivity` by swiping it left or right.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26771651/android-new-inbox-app-style-listview-with-swipe-left-and-right it may helps you

Comment: No that sliding each row in the listview, I want to do the sliding part in the next activity, I think you haven't got the question right?

Comment: I think it depends upon how long the details are. Does it need scrolling? How frequently will the user check the details?

Comment: @Sufian, it doesn't need scrolling, its just an half page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have a **Custom Object** and **ArrayList** of this object.
You need to have an adapter to Show this Arraylist into Listview
When you clicked the list item you need to pass your object from **ListActivity** to your **DetailActivity**

I think you are doing this fine until this part.

Then now, you can use **ViewPager** and its **adapter** in your **DetailActivity**.
When you click the list item, you need to *pass your Arraylist* and *your object index* to the **DetailActivity**.

In the **DetailActivity**, get your **Arraylist**, set your List into **ViewPager adapter**, find your **object via index**(that you clicked) and **set ViewPager page index** as your wanted item index.

If you manage this correctly, you can slide details of your content. You can ask ma anything to make this clear.

There is a tutorial of Using the ViewPager: http://architects.dzone.com/articles/android-tutorial-using

Comment: thanks well explained, I'll contact you for queries.:)

Answer (score 1):

You could go with a `ExpandableListView`. No need to open a new screen or doing something which becomes hard to manage like `Fragment`s. The user can show/hide detail just by clicking on the item.

> A view that shows items in a vertically scrolling two-level list. This
>   differs from the `ListView` by allowing two levels: groups which can
>   individually be expanded to show its children. The items come from the
>   `ExpandableListAdapter` associated with this view.