# Two activity transition like Gmail

Tags: android, android-transitions

I've two activities, Activity **A** and activity **B**.

I need to set some transition when user navigate from **A** to **B** to be exactly as in gmail.

I've tried: (in activity **A**)

```
startActivity(activityBIntent);
ActivityA.this.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_out_right, 0);
```

But I cannot achieve the same animation like in Gmail.

Comment: Detailed discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253965/complete-working-sample-of-the-gmail-three-fragment-animation-scenario