# Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class fragment Android

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I want to show the list+Description in tablet view. Code below works fine with Portrait mode but stopped when in Landscape mode. Is it something wrong?

**MainActivity**

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.app.ListFragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        // if run on phone, isSinglePane = true
        // if run on tablet, isSinglePane = false
        boolean isSinglePane;

        static String[] month ={
                "January", "February", "March", "April",
                "May", "June", "July", "August",
                "September", "October", "November", "December"};

        public static class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {

            @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

                ListAdapter myArrayAdapter =
                        new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, month);
                setListAdapter(myArrayAdapter);

            }

        }

        public static class MyDetailFragment extends Fragment {

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_detailfragment, null);
                return view;
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            View v = findViewById(R.id.phone_container);
            if(v == null){
                //it's run on tablet
                isSinglePane = false;
       /*
        * MyListFragment and MyDetailFragment have been loaded in XML,
        * no need load.
        */

            }else{
                //it's run on phone
                //Load MyListFragment programmatically
                isSinglePane = true;

                if(savedInstanceState == null){
                    //if's the first time created
                    MyListFragment myListFragment = new MyListFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.phone_container, myListFragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Layout/activityMain.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/titles"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
             />

    </FrameLayout>
```

**res/Layout-land/activitymain.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Normal" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/phone_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**LayoutdetailFragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_detailfragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Detail Fragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Error**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.fyp_awais.tab, PID: 3974
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fyp_awais.tab/com.example.fyp_awais.tab.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class fragment
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class fragment
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
>                         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
>                         at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
>                         at com.example.fyp_awais.tab.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:56)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
>                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                         at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:362)
>                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
>                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>                         at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:604)
>                         at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
>                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2108)
>                         at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5328)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
>                         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378) 
>                         at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145) 
>                         at com.example.fyp_awais.tab.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:56) 
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
>   Application terminated.

Comment: post your error log.

Comment: @user6750923, as per your code snippet, I can't found the phone_container in any of xml file, can you update the xml of main activity

Comment: @TejaDroid Updated

Comment: @Ahamed See the error in question

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are getting error in **landscape** mode? because in **landscape** its running fine and in **portrait** mode you are not using dynamic fragment so that you need to extend **Fragment Activity** instead of Activity to run the fragment.  It would be good if you use dynamic fragment instead hard-coded.

Change your layout-port/main_activity to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:id="@+id/phone_container2"
    >

  // remove hard coded fragment

</FrameLayout>
```

// your full solution

**Main Activity**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // if run on phone, isSinglePane = true
    // if run on tablet, isSinglePane = false
    boolean isSinglePane;

    static String[] month ={
            "January", "February", "March", "April",
            "May", "June", "July", "August",
            "September", "October", "November", "December"};

    public static class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            ListAdapter myArrayAdapter =
                    new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, month);
            setListAdapter(myArrayAdapter);

        }

    }

    public static class MyDetailFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_detailfragment, null);
            return view;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View v = findViewById(R.id.phone_container);
        if(v == null){
            //it's run on tablet
            isSinglePane = false;

            //if's the first time created
            MyDetailFragment myListFragment = new MyDetailFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.phone_container2, myListFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();



       /*
        * MyListFragment and MyDetailFragment have been loaded in XML,
        * no need load.
        */

        }else{
            //it's run on phone
            //Load MyListFragment programmatically
            isSinglePane = true;


                //if's the first time created
                MyListFragment myListFragment = new MyListFragment();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.phone_container, myListFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
    }
}
```

**port:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:id="@+id/phone_container2"
    >

  <!--  <fragment
        android:id="@+id/titles"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />-->

</FrameLayout>
```

**land:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Normal" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/phone_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example of dynamic fragment?

Comment: I  am using a tablet Virtual Device (Nexus-9). It works find in portrait mode but stopped on landscape.

Comment: For landscape you are using dynamic just like that.

Comment: I did not understand your answer. I do not have `-port` folder. I have res/layout-land and res/layout.

Comment: That is not a problem res/layout also be fine if you are putting your portrait code their.

Comment: Same problem. Giving `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class fragment` in landscape mode. I am running code on Nexus 9. (AVD ).

Comment: Totally useless. I want a detailed fragment ('List' on the left side and 'Details' on right side. ) But your suggestion deleted the list and showing only the detail in lanscape mode.

Comment: You need to edit the answer according to your need. I can just help you how it works.

Comment: Dear @Pushpendra I already mentioned in the question `I want to show the list+Description in tablet view`.

Comment: You can put listview inside detail fragment and use it bro.

Comment: Choudary I want (list + desc) side by side in tablet. Kindly see my question above and this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41339189/need-a-working-example-of-handling-large-and-small-screens-on-android`

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is on `<fragment>` of xml file

If you want to use the [fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) in xml then there need to define the class of that fragment as

```
<fragment
        class="com.example.android.app.fragmentName"
        android:id="@+id/titles"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

else define fragment in-side code and set FrameLayout in xml as

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/titles"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Yes. it is working now. But  I want (list + desc) side by side in tablet.

Comment: @user6750923, Please check this link, "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253965/complete-working-sample-of-the-gmail-three-fragment-animation-scenario", I think you got answer of your question. also one more "https://commonsware.com/Android/previews/large-screen-strategies-and-tactics" explain strategy ...